# How to split a row into two strings and copy the second string in a separate column in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, split

I have a column which is named "`Firstname`" and contains

```
Firstname Lastname
```

and I want to create another column called `Lastname` and cut the `Lastname` from the "`Firstaname`" column and paste it on the "`Lastname`" column, for multiple rows.

before

```
Firstname
---------
Bob Weller
```

after

```
Firstname | Lastname
----------|---------
Bob       | Weller
```

**edit:**
after `Lastname` there might be a number or other strings such as ( ) etc.. which should go to the Lastname column

Comment: What is the seperator between first name and last name?

Comment: How are you defining when the last name starts?  What if someone had a first name with two capital letters in it (e.g. DeAnna)?  Or are you not concerned with those cases?

Comment: The names is not separated with nothing other than a capital letter ?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What about hyphenated names for married females?  Like NancySmith-Johnson or NanySmithJohnson.  You need some sort of delimiter or normalization here.  There's a lot of room for error here without something that defines where the first name ends and the last name begins.

Comment: Without a clear delimiter this will get messy very quickly. Scenarios like what Siyual and Kris Gruttemeyer described will definitely complicate things.

Comment: Apologies, edited: there is a whitespace delimiter

Comment: The title asks for this to be on two rows, the example shows it as one row but two columns.  And string functions are different in various RDBMS, so we need to know which it is that you're using *(MS SQL Server 2008?  MS SQL Server 2012?  MySQL?  Oracle?  etc, etc.)*.

Comment: I am not concerned for cases such as DeAnna etc

Comment: You are right, just edited it. The title was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query splits it into FirstName and LastName at the first space.

```
SELECT  FirstNameLastName,
substring(FirstNameLastName, 0, charindex(' ', FirstNameLastName) -1) as FirstName,
substring(FirstNameLastName, charindex(' ', FirstNameLastName) -1,len(FirstNameLastName)) as LastName
from [Table]
```

To modify your table and move the old column into new columns, you can do the following:
Alter your table first to create your new columns:

```
Alter Table [TableName]
Add FirstName varchar(50),
LastName Varchar(50)
```

Then use an update statement to move the values into it

```
Update Table [TableName]
Set FirstName = substring(FirstNameLastName, 0, charindex(' ', FirstNameLastName)-1),
LastName = substring(FirstNameLastName, charindex(' ', FirstNameLastName)-1,len(FirstNameLastName))
```

This should move the values from the old column into the two new columns.

Comment: Beat me by one second. Well played, worthy adversary.  However, your code will add a space at the end of first name and a space at the beginning of last name.

Comment: Lol, are sql is almost identical too.

Comment: Thanks. And how can I create that column and insert the result, i.e. create the Firstname and Lastname columns and insert the resulted first names and last names? I guess something with insert into?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to add and update the new columns.

Comment: Remember, you're still adding a space at the end of first name and a space at the beginning of last name.  add a -1 and a +1 after the charindex functions.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer - Though the query will then error on any string that doesn't have a space in it.

Comment: I'm assuming (i know, i know) that the delimiter between names is constant and present on all.  If we assume that, then -1 and +1 are correct.

Comment: Should we just use the sql Trim function so that it takes care of it whether there is a space or not? It is splitting it at the space though so if it is not there it won't work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you want then split into 2 *columns* not *rows* then something like this should do:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(WholeName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', WholeName) - 1) AS Firstname,
SUBSTRING(WholeName, CHARINDEX(' ', WholeName) + 1, len(FirstName)) AS LastName 
FROM MyTable
```

NOTE: This is assuming that EVERY record has a space between first and last names.

Answer (score 0):

The following is similar to the accepted answer, except:
- It deals with strings that don't contain a space
- It uses `OUTER APPLY` to avoid re-writing the `CHARINDEX` multiple times
- It doesn't include the space as the last character of the new first name
- It doesn't include the space as the first character of the new last name

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN lookup.first_space = 0 THEN ''
    ELSE SUBSTRING(yourTable.firstName, 1, lookup.first_space - 1)
  END   AS new_firstName,
  CASE
    WHEN lookup.first_space = 0 THEN yourTable.firstName
    ELSE SUBSTRING(yourTable.firstName, lookup.first_space + 1, 9999)
  END   AS new_lastName
FROM
  yourTable
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', yourTable.firstName, 0) AS first_space) AS lookup
```